# Python code works in the shell, but not when encapsulated within a function

Tags: python, arduino

I wrote a sketch for Arduino that lights up an Adafruit NeoPixel Ring with 12 LEDs. It works fine if I use the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE to enter data.

The way it works is I give it a string and it uses that string to determine what RGB values to use for the LEDs. For example if I input 'r100g0b0w0' the LEDs will permanently display a red color. I could then input another string, for example 'r0g0b0w100', to give the LEDs another color (in this example, white).

I wrote a python function that interfaces with the Arduino (the Arduino is connected via USB to my computer) and enables the user to enter the colors they want and display them on the Arduino in real time (i.e. without uploading a new sketch to the Arduino).

The problem I am having is with the light_LED function at the bottom of the python file. It is supposed to use the given integers red_intensity, green_intensity, blue_intensity, and white_intensity to format a string similar to the ones given above. Then it converts the string from UTF to byte format and sends the string to the Arduino.

I used the python 3.6 shell in windows 10 command prompt.

If I run every line from the function "light_LED" separately (substituting appropriate integer values for the intensity numbers given as arguments), the NeoPixel Ring LEDs light up.

But when I run the function with integer arguments, the LED does not light up. So if I open the python shell by typing this in the command prompt:

```
py -3.6
```

And then I copy-paste this in the python shell:

```
import serial
import time

red_intensity=100
green_intensity=0
blue_intensity=0
white_intensity=0
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 115200)
time.sleep(2)
rgb_string = (
    'r' + str(red_intensity) + 'g' + str(green_intensity) + 'b'
    + str(blue_intensity) + 'w' + str(white_intensity)
)
byte_rgb_string = rgb_string.encode()
ser.write(byte_rgb_string)
```

The shell prints out the number of bytes sent (10) and the LEDs light up as they are supposed to. But if I run the function containing identical code by typing this in the windows command prompt:

```
py -3.6 -i light.py
```

And then this in the python shell:

```
light_LED(100, 0, 0, 0)
```

Nothing is printed and the LEDs on the AdaFruit device do not light up.

### Here's my Python file:

```
import serial
import time

def light_LED(red_intensity, green_intensity, blue_intensity, white_intensity):
    ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 115200)
    time.sleep(2)
    rgb_string = (
        'r' + str(red_intensity) + 'g' + str(green_intensity) + 'b'
        + str(blue_intensity) + 'w' + str(white_intensity)
    )
    byte_rgb_string = rgb_string.encode()
    ser.write(byte_rgb_string)
```

### Here's my Arduino sketch if you want to see it as well:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN 5

#define NUM_LEDS 12

#define BRIGHTNESS 20

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUM_LEDS, PIN, NEO_GRBW + NEO_KHZ800);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  strip.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.peek() != -1) {
    displayGivenColors();
    // This prevents looping until additional data is sent by the computer.
    // This is necessary because loops seem to interrupt the displayGivenColors function.
    while(Serial.peek() == -1) {
    }
  }
}

void displayGivenColors(){
  // Enter the different color intensities separated by non-integer characters. 
  // The first number represents red, the next represent blue, then green, then white.
  // For example, the entry 'r255b0g0w0' will produce a full intensity red color.
  int redIntensity = Serial.parseInt();
  int blueIntensity = Serial.parseInt();
  int greenIntensity = Serial.parseInt();
  int whiteIntensity = Serial.parseInt();

  setAllPixelsToColor(redIntensity, blueIntensity, greenIntensity, whiteIntensity);
  strip.show();
}

void setAllPixelsToColor(int redNumber, int blueNumber, int greenNumber, int whiteNumber) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.Color(redNumber, blueNumber, greenNumber, whiteNumber) );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I type "py -3.6" in the command prompt and it opens up the Python 3.6.0 shell. I don't see why there would be any problem with me using windows command prompt.

Comment: Your code defines a function but does not call it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Yes my python file does not call my function, it only defines it. But I run the file interactively and once the shell is open I run the function. First I type this: py -3.6 -i light.py which opens the python shell. Next I type this in the opened python shell: light_LED(100, 0, 0, 0)